# Display Condition in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to display background color in `<td>` when certain condition meets. For example:

```
 @{
   if (item.Required ==true)
   {                           
    <td style="background-color:lightgreen;">
   }
   else {
    <td>
   } 
 }
```

But it does not work. How do I do this? Thanks.

or short for

```
 <td @item.Required? style="background-color:lightgreen":white>
```

Comment: "_But it does not work._" What happens instead? Show us a complete example we can replicate so we can better help.

Comment: The error message says missing close tag </td>. I am new to Razor, it must be my razor code syntax is not correct.

Comment: Your html is invalid as one (or both) `<td>` lacks a closing tag.

Comment: I want to close <td> after a block of code. How to correct add background color CSS in <td>?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I add a class in the `<td>` and have CSS in external file instead of inline CSS.

```
<td class=@{ if (item.Required == true) { @Html.Raw("greentext")} }>
```

Comment: That's a solution but it comes at a price.  @Html.Raw opens up your application to XSS attacks.

Comment: `Raw()` here is OK. It's a concern if you use `Raw()` with unsanitized user input.

Answer (score 0):

You need properly closed tags or the parser will complain.

```
@if (item.Required ==true)
{                           
    <td style="background-color:lightgreen;">
    </td>
}
else {
   <td>
   </td>
}
```

If you want to do it with one-line you can use an *explicit expression*

```
<td class="@(item.Required ? "green-text" : "" )"></td>
```